There exists a continuous graph homomorphism cantor scheme
Let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be sequences of elements of the form $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ with the property that $|s_n| = n$ and $\forall s \in 2^{<\mathbb{N}} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}(s \subseteq s_n)$(same thing for $t_n$). From this, then we can define a graph having cantor space as vertex set and edge relation defined as $x E y \iff \exists n(s_n \subseteq x \land s_n \subseteq y \land x(n) \neq y(n) \land \forall m > n(x(n) = y(m))$. We can denote this graph as $G_{(s_n)}$ similarly for $t_n$. I am having trouble showing that there exists a continuous homomorphism between $G_{(s_n)}$ and $G_{(t_n)}$. I have been trying to use $N_s := \{x \in 2^\mathbb{N}: s \subseteq x\}$. One method I tried to do but realized it didn't work was using a cantor scheme and given any $s \in 2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ then I would pick the least $t_n'$ so that $s \subseteq t_n'$ define $A_s = N_{t_n'}$. But when I went to construct my cantor scheme I realized  that the disjointness property might not hold e.g. what happens if $t_1 = 1$, $t_2 = 11$, $t_3 = 001$ then $0 \subset t_3$ and $00 \subset t_3$ but $A_{00} = A_0 = N_{t_3}$. I tried a different method were I just pick least $t_n'$ only at $s_n$ but then ran into issues too.
